# Is a document "Roman Numeraled", "Roman Numbered"...?

Tags: word-choice

If I am discussing a book that uses Roman numerals to break sections, would it be correct to say that the book uses

> Roman numeraled sections

or

> Roman numbered sections?

I can't find many credible uses of "numeraled", and "numbered" doesn't sound right.

Comment: Interestingly, there are [some instances of *Roman-numeralled*](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=roman+numeralled&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&hl=en&sa=X&nfpr=1&spell=) out there. Notice the double-L and the hyphen.

Comment: That's encouraging. Does that, then, give credence to "parallelled"?

Comment: I did see [this](http://www.thegloss.com/2012/11/07/culture/lobster-theft-323/) too.

Comment: Yes, certainly you find people using *parallelled*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Definition of numeral](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/numeral):

> noun: a figure, symbol, or group of figures or symbols denoting a
>   number.  a word expressing a number.
>  adjective: of or denoting a
>   number.

So, it be wrong to use a past tense of *numeral*. And have a look at this ngram which suggests that *Roman numbered*, or *Roman numeraled* don't really have any appearances in books (agreeing to what you found out).
[image] 
So I would rather go along what @gmcgath suggests and use an alternative like:

1. the book uses sections numbered in Roman numerals.
2. the book uses sections with Roman numerals.
3. the book uses sections divided (grouped) into Roman numerals.

etc.